# Differential equation involving composition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, integral-equations

I've been studying Euler's method to approximate a solution to a differential equation in an algorithm class.

I faced a weird differential equation in a mathematics exercise, and I wanted to know if Euler method was applicable to it. This equation is :
$$f(x)=\int_0^{ax}f(t)dt + g(x)$$
$g$ being a known function (for which I know the derivative).

I've tried to transform the equation a bit, and I'm getting :
$$\frac{df}{dt}(t)=af(at)+\frac{dg}{dt}(t)$$

However, in my lecture, Euler's method is applicable to $$\frac{du}{dt}(x)=f(x,u(x))$$
And here, my equation depends on $f(at)$ and not $f(t)$. Is Euler method still applicable?

If not, is there any other method I could use?

Comment: In the derivative of the equation you also need the derivative of $g$. This is no ODE, thus Euler or general RK methods are not applicable. The equation connects two loci, in this form it is worse than delay-DE. You can of course approximate the integral via Riemann sums or trapezoidal formulas ...

Comment: @LutzL : $g$ is a function that I know and for which I also know the derivative (e.g. $x^2$ or $\cos$), I regulary face such thing in ODE (even first order), but not when composition (here with $at$) comes in.